# Renstalling ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Have installed ubuntu 16.04 on my computer.but it crashed due to low graphics card.so decided to reinstall ubuntu.but i want to keep my desktop files safe.how can i irenstall ubuntu without losing the desktop files?

Comment: Boot with live cd and take backup of your data.

Comment: backup your Ubuntu and restore when done

Comment: Or reinstall Ubuntu without formating your HDD